# Java 8 stream groupingBy reducing with custom function

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I retrieved a `List<Item>` from some datasource

```
@Data
public class Item {
  private String name;
  private String owner;
  private boolean enabled;
  ...
}
```

The content is like:

```
name     owner        enabled
====     =====        =======
foo      boss         true
foo      under-boss   false
bar      kinda-boss   true
buzz     boss         false
buzz     dude         true
```

My goal is to get a list with one line for each `name` that contains the whole Item for most important `owner`. So:

```
name     owner        enabled
====     =====        =======
foo      boss         true
bar      kinda-boss   true
buzz     boss         false
```

I tried:

```
listItem.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Item::getName))
```

that gets me a nice Map of name -> List containing the various items with that name.

But my problem is to process the List there to return the full Item of the bossiest owner. The documentation explains how `groupingBy(Item::getName, Collectors.reducing(false, Item::isEnabled, Boolean::max)` would return a boolean max value for each name but I'm looking for the whole Item, not the average length of the owner name or something.

The most important owner is determined by a method (it's actually based on several fields). I can write a (a, b) -> { if (....) return a else return b; }.

Comment: What are the possible values for `owner`? How do you determine if someone is "bossier" than someone else?

Comment: How are you identifying most important `owner`

Comment: I have an elaborate function that tells me which Item is more important. This is a simplification, it's actually based on various fields from the object.

Comment: Post the signature of that method then. We're missing some info.

Comment: Something like `groupingBy(Item::getName, maxBy((a, b) -> magic)`?

Comment: @Tunaki: that's it. That's what I was looking for. I had tried it because magic was returning a or b instead of a comparison between the two. Thanks !

Comment: @EricDarchis You could also use the overloaded version of `toMap` and use this logic in the merge function you can provide in case two values maps to the same key (the nice thing is that you get a `Map<A, B>` instead of a `Map<A, Optional<B>>`).

Comment: @AlexisC. Nice suggestion because with the Map<String, Optional<Item>>, I have to do `.values().stream().filter(Optional::isPresent).map(Optional::get).collect(Collectors.toList())`
However, I'm not sure how to use the toMap in that context.

Comment: @EricDarchis Check the answers in the duplicate!

Comment: Of course, it also works with a function that returns either `a` or `b`: `groupingBy(Item::getName, reducing((a, b) -> magic))`